# Fourier series of a following function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am supposed to find a Fourier series of a following function I have tried a number of different ideas but have been unable to solve it:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^2 \cdot e^{\cos(x)}-1}$$

Comment: Do you mean: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^2 \cdot e^{\cos(x)}-1}$$

Comment: Yes actually I was not sure how to format the text correctly will try to fix it now,thank you.

Comment: For your information, you can fix the dot product with "\cdot" and the powers by doing this: "e^{\cos(x)}"